# Uniswap V3 SwapMath.computeSwapStep doesn't give same results as quoterContract.callStatic.quoteExactInputSingle

Tags: uniswapv3, swaps

When I use the @uniswap/v3-sdk SwapMath.computeSwapStep I get a different result from quoterContract.callStatic.quoteExactInputSingle.. it's also off from the result I get from the UI at https://app.uniswap.org/swap. I believe there is enough liquidity to do this in a single tick range. I want to use computeSwapStep so that I don't have to call the blockchain to calculate amountOut.

I'm accounting for the decimals and my output is close, but not right.

QUOTER_CONTRACT_ADDRESS = '0xb27308f9F90D607463bb33eA1BeBb41C27CE5AB6'

blockNumber = 13585746

POOL = 0x127452f3f9cdc0389b0bf59ce6131aa3bd763598

feeTier = 3000

liquidity = 622042174869115692

sqrtPriceX96   =  14670974498071099394760411

sqrtRatioTargetX96 = 250541448375047931186413801

Sol Amount IN = 10000

WETH out from quoteExactInputSingle = 226.4383366046434405

WETH out from computeSwapStep = 268.630460850352195962

WETH out from UI https://app.uniswap.org/swap = 212.393